# mysql-2.8.1 gem error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

So when I tried to run `bundle install` I get an error for mysql-2.8.1.gem. I tried doing clean up command but still get the same error. This is the error message:

> Fetching: mysql-2.8.1.gem (100%)
>   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions into the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.

Comment: It's stating very clearly that you, or the user it's starting on behave of, does not have permissions to the folder...

Comment: How can I change the permission of the folder. I am the only user.

Comment: Voted to move this to Superuser, cuz it's not a programming question.  It'd help to know what *nix you're using - Ubuntu?

Comment: This is on topic for StackOverflow because it concerns "software tools commonly used by programmers" (see the FAQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rubygems tries to install gems for system-wide access (in a system-wide folder) by default, but it has a mode that lets you install them in a directory in your home directory.

One option is to install the gem sytemwide, you need root permission. On most modern linux distributions you can do this by using `sudo gem install ...`.

If you really wanted this in your home directory, you should be aware that rubygems is not configured to automatically fall back to installing gems in your home directory when you try to install as a normal user. It prefers to give you an error message (the one you see here) unless you specifically indicate that you want to install the gem in your home directory. You can tell rubygems to install in your home directory by using `gem install --user-install ...`

Comment: I figured out the problem. Just reinstalled mysql. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments above, this is a permissions issue, and it would be correct to move it to Superuser since it's not a programming problem.

What is actually happening though, is that when you're running bundle install and not using [rvm](https://rvm.io), bundle will try to save your freshly bundled gems to the default gem directory, which usually lives somewhere in /usr.

A normal user doesn't have write access to this directory. You could try to run the same command with sudo, i.e. `sudo bundle install`. That might work.

I'd really suggest that you use rvm for doing stuff like this, since it really helps keeping your gemsets clean and you won't run into these problems.

Comment: You should never use `sudo bundle install`, per the instructions in the [bundle-install manpage](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html)